# Add 30 second to current system time in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-ide

I am working on script where i have to write command such that it will add 30 second to current time.
I have got current time in my script, but facing problem in adding 30 second to the current time.
Is there any command/ solution for this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var timePlusThirtySeconds = new Date().getMilliseconds() + 30 * 1000;
```

Or are you actually talking about setting the system clock into the future.

Comment: solution is working fine. but can we add 30 sec to the system time like, current time - 1hrs 30min 40 sec and by adding 30 sec o/p - 1hrs 31min 10sec  ?? is it possible?

Comment: The selenium pause command will achieve this, if you're patient enough to wait.  I don't think you can set the system clock from Selenium